# If $x$ is a nonzero vector in $X,$ and $y \in Y,$ show there exists a bounded linear map $T:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $T(x) = y.$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces. 
    If $x$ is a nonzero vector in $X,$ and $y \in Y,$ show there exists a bounded linear map $T:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $T(x) = y.$

I have no clue on how to start. I think Hahn-Banach theorem might be used here to show existence of a linear map. However, I do now know which sublinear functional to use here.

Any hint would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Following nonlinear thought's comment, I constructed the following proof:

Let $V = sp\{ x \} = \{ \alpha x: \alpha \in \mathbb{K} \}.$ 
Clearly $V$ is a linear subspace of $X.$
Define $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ given by $f(\alpha x) = 1$.
By the Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exists an extension $\hat{f}:X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $\hat{f}|_V = f$ and $\|\hat{f}\| = \| f \|. $
Define $T:X \rightarrow Y$ given by 
$$T(w) = y \cdot f(w)$$ 
for all $w \in X.$

We claim that $T$ is a linear bounded map such that $T(x) = y.$

Clearly $T(x) = y \cdot f(x) = y \cdot 1 = y.$
For any $w_1, w_2 \in X,$ we have 
$$T(w_1 + w_2) = y \cdot f(w_1 + w_2) = y\cdot (f(w_1) +f(w_2)) = y \cdot f(w_1) + y \cdot f(w_2) = T(w_1) + T(w_2).$$
For any $\beta \in \mathbb{K}$ and $w \in X,$ we have 
$$T(\alpha w) = y \cdot f(\alpha w) = y \cdot \alpha f(w) = \alpha y \cdot f(w) = \alpha \cdot T(w).$$
Therefore, $T$ is linear. 
For any $w \in X$ with $\| w \| \leq 1,$ we have
$$\| T(w)\| = \|y \cdot f(w)  \| = \| y \| \cdot |f(w)| \leq \| y \| \cdot \| f \| \cdot  \|w \| \leq \| y \| \cdot \| f \|.$$
Hence, 
$$\|T \| = \sup_{\| w \| \leq}\|T(w) \| \leq \| y \| \cdot \\ f \|.$$
Therefore, $T$ is bounded.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 3):

Since $x$ is nonzero by Hahn Banach Theorem there exist continuous functional, say $f \in X^*$ such that $f(x) = 1.$

Now define $T(a)=yf(a)$ for all $a \in X.$